# Do invertible matrices share the same eigenvalues and the same eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given the following:

*If v is an eigenvector of an invertible A ∈ Mn×n(R) with corresponding eigenvalue λ, then cv is an eigenvector of A^-1 for all non-zero scalars c.

So, if

Av = λ * v can I say that A^-1 * v = λ * v ??

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Start with $Av=\lambda v$ and multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$. See what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. Can you see why ?

Comment: Yeas sure, thanks.